# Android RecyclerView wrong childCount

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a simple RecyclerView with an adapter and sometimes I need to get the count of child views in my RecyclerView outside the adapter.

I use: `((LinearLayoutManager) myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).getChildCount()` for this. But I never get the real count of views inside the RecyclerView.

For example, I add 10 items to my list and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. After this I call `((LinearLayoutManager) myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).getChildCount()` I get 4.

Can someone explain me how to get the real count of views inside the RecyclerView?

Comment: Can't you call `adapter.getItemCount()`?

Comment: Yes I can, but I need to get view count because after this I need to perform actions over some of child views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the real count of views. If adapter has 10 items and `((LinearLayoutManager) myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).getChildCount()` returns you 4, there is nothing wrong with that.

The count of items in the model (adapter) and the count of views are **not** the same thing.

`RecyclerView` doesn't hold views for all 10 items in memory, it only has 4 in your case. When you scroll, it reuses those 4 views for displaying different items. The purpose of this is improving the rendering performance.

If you want to get 10, then you should use `adapter.getCount()` instead.